# how to change color of name of frame in rviz as shown in figures?

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to change the color of names of frames from white to black, see figure 1, the background and name are white color while in figure 2 the background color is black and the name is white in rviz.

I need to alter between them

[image: C:\fakepath\2.png]

and

[image: C:\fakepath\1.png]

**updated**
After @Orhan  helped me, it works fine

you can see them with black color.

[image: image description]

please help me

thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324104/how-to-change-color-of-name-of-frame-in-rviz-as-shown-in-figures?/) by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2019-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may need to download the code and change this line, then build your own RViz:
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/melodic-devel/src/rviz/default_plugin/tf_display.cpp#L570

```
frame->axes_->setToDefaultColors();
frame->name_text_->setColor(Ogre::ColourValue::White); // <--
frame->parent_arrow_->setHeadColor(ARROW_HEAD_COLOR);
frame->parent_arrow_->setShaftColor(ARROW_SHAFT_COLOR);
```

Line number can be different based on your ROS distro. You'll be needing the version of source code that was used to supply your distro's binaries.

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2019-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-05-28**:
Thank you, I will try to download it

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2020-07-15**:
I downloaded it for kinetic from [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/tree/kinetic-devel) and put it on my /catkin_ws/src/ and used **catkin_make**, it built successfully....>[100%] Built target rviz_default_plugin
but I don't know how to launch it.
@Orhan, please help me.
I used "**rosrun rviz rviz**" but it is the same befor.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2020-07-15**:
Try entering `roscd rviz` command. If it brings you to `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rviz`, then something is wrong with your terminal environment. Try re-sourcing your workspace after deleting `build`, `devel`, `install` folders and building back. e.g. `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2020-07-15**:
I changed this line from

`frame->name_text_->setColor(Ogre::ColourValue::White)`;
to
`frame->name_text_->setColor(Ogre::ColourValue::Black)`;
then used
`source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`

It works fine, thank you so much for your help @Orhan .

Note: all this modification is in the workstation part, not is in the robot part.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2020-07-15**:
@Orhan what about color of arrows which joint two frames, you can see it yellow color, right?.

Can I change it to another color for example black or red?

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2020-07-15**:
I didn't check the source code or the rviz gui for that. But if you believe in yourself, you can find it in the source code in case there's no option in rviz.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2020-07-15**:
@Orhan  thanks